# Apple regulations regarding sensitive data send over internet

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm currently working on an app that connects to a web service and exchanges data in different ways.
I connect to the service with https.

At some point i need to send from my app a credit card number.
Since i never done something similar, I'm not sure there is something more i should do to encrypt the CC number, or it will work this way ( not get rejected ).

Can someone who did this before advise ?

Regards,

Comment: You are walking into a PCI compliance minefield, plus putting yourself at risk of having your app rejected from the appstore. Why do you need to take credit card details in-app? Could you not use in-app purchase?

Comment: The service handles payments. Basically i make reservations for limos. So i need to send the cc details so the service be able to process the payments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect via HTTPS (and do it right) the CC number will get encrypted and that will be fine. But you could get into trouble with Apple since if you do payments from your app, you are urged to use in-app purchases. If you do not want that, you have to find a smart way to take the payment process out of your app, like letting the user create an account on your website, set their CC info there and connect from the app using their account.

Comment: As i got it if the products are physical (like a picture) you can still do payments separate. I guess this is my case also. But I'll have to check this again.